# Calculating an angle between diagonal and base in trapezoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a small geometric problem. Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid ($AB||CD$) where the diagonals meet at $E$. We know that $\angle ABD=34^\circ$, $BC=9cm$ and $AC=12cm$. How to calculate $\angle BAC$?

[image]

This question is taken from my textbook. I have tried the law of sines but without any success. I also thought to insert the trapezoid into a circle but didn't find out how does it help.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin, Unfortunately no. Copied as it is from the textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\angle BAC$ is not unique.

Draw a circle $(BDC)$ which is fixed so that $BC = 9$ and $\angle BDC = 34$. Clearly $A$ is on a circle with center at $C$ and radius $r=12$. But $A$ is also on parallel to $CD$ through $B$.

Now when you move $D$ on circle $(BDC)$ you get a differnt values for a searched angle. (Play in geogebra.)

Comment: So there is a mistake in my textbook?

Comment: Obviously......

Comment: @vesii Maybe length $AB$ is given ?

Comment: Why is $B$ the centre of your second circle?

Comment: Sorry , I meant $C$

Comment: @JeanMarie Unfortunately it is not. Copied the question as is :/

Comment: A rather strange thing : what is the interest to give a name to the crossing point $E$ ?